# Building a new static html view by selecting a new request in the language menu

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

When developing a multi language website in ASP.NET, I read a lot of things like; routing, localization and CultureInfo. My basic knowledge about ASP.NET with MVC5 doesn't allow to go through with these advanced skills. As well, the project for this restaurant, doesn’t need to be that advanced. **It just need to load the correct language request with the new static html from the selected language** through a new HomeController or whatever is needed.
My Project is currently online and when selecting French a new Index is loaded >>https://www.grandcafelamot.be/Language/Change?LanguageAbbrevation=fr. The same Index is been loaded for 'Nederlands', but this an issue I should solve later, I guess. But as I said, my main problem for the moment is, when selecting a language in the topbar language menu. **From where can I build up a new Index and render it with the prober Body.** 
A second thing is that you've maybe noticed, **I was capable to translate the topbar menu by resources when selecting French.** Though, when clicking by example on [Service-FR](https://www.grandcafelamot.be/Home/Service) I am not able to load the new request Index with the correct language of this Link (Service-FR). 
I've been searching so much to find a simple solution.
Thank you for reading my post and may be put me on the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you want. But you can return a different View based on a language setting. Then you simply need to create an additional cshtml file in the correct language, in this case the `index-fr.cshtml`.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new Models.HomeViewModel();

    if (MijnTaal == "nl-NL")
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    else
    {
        return View("index-fr", model);
    }
}
```

Or write a simple method for it so you do not need to write those if/else statements every time.

```
public string getAction()
{
    string action = ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
    if (MijnTaal == "nl-NL")
    {
        return action;
    }
    else
    {
        return action + "-fr";
    }
}
```

And then

```
return View(getAction(), model);
```